# MongoDB - Ubuntu 15.04 missing packages

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I've updated my Ubuntu 14.04 to the latest 15.04. Since then Mongo failed to run. can run the command `mongo` and it'll advise the version and so on but server will not run: `sudo service mongod start` as normal.

When I ran: `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` it failed with the error in the screen shot below:

[image: Screen Shot]

I completely purged mongo and re-installed, followed the instructions [from here.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) However when I ran `sudo apt-get update` I noticed the below packages were 404'ing. See Screen shot below.

[image: Second Screenshot]

If anyone could shed any light on this would be great?

Comment: It won't I'm afraid. You see the packages cannot be found for the install. I need to know if the issue is strictly with the latest version of Ubuntu. I've installed mongoDB on many systems. Just got this error since updating 15.04

Comment: See also: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17742

Comment: @niall-lonergan can you tell how you slove this im also having this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989107/mongodb-installation-not-working-on-ubuntu-15-04?noredirect=1#comment48097622_29989107

Comment: If anyone has a 32-bit OS, manually download the legacy zip file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no build available for Ubuntu 15.04. Check this page for all builds: https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#development

Comment: Thought as much. Thank you for the help. I was able to add "trusty" into the echo path and now it's pulling from that repo.

Answer (score 7):

Following instructions from this page page http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

but with slighty changed second step **2. Create a list file for MongoDB**:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

I put **trusty** (code name for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) instead of *$(lsb_release -sc)* which issues *vivid* as codename for 15.04

I see now that @Nail Lonergan already commented echo path change...

Comment: smart, but are you able to start mondog service?

Comment: yes with this: mongod -v --dbpath /mnt/datapart/david/dev/mongodb/data/db
and access it with:
mongo                                                      
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2015-08-17T21:38:09.437+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-08-17T21:38:09.437+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.
...

Answer (score 1):

After having heaps of issues, finally this is how I installed it,

## Ubuntu 15.04

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install -y mongodb
sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv
sudo service mongodb status
```

if not running

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

## Install PHP Driver

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo pecl install mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

https://sonnguyen.ws/install-mongodb-mongo-php-in-ubuntu/

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb

ps -ef|grep mongo

sudo pecl install mongo

sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear
```